# Chrome session stops loading anything after copying large image to clipboard

Tags: google-chrome, memory, crash, virtual-memory, memory-management

So I was copying a 15000x8000 image from Wikipedia to my clipboard in Windows 10, which resulted in the browser freezing for a bit. It unfroze and I thought everything was fine after that but noticed new incognito tabs (chrome://newtab) weren't loading and crashed resulting in `RESULT_CODE_HUNG` Still my old tabs still worked fine and searching things on the search bar still worked, albeit a little slower

https://i.ibb.co/n80NH7K/image.png

Then after a while old tabs stopped loading and gave the same error as newtabs, and soon I couldn't search anything entirely. I had over 50 tabs in an incognito and over 300 tabs in a normal window at the time, with history, cookies, localstorage, and all, that weren't going to be saved if I closed my chrome process.

So I freaked out and tried copying almost everything from my userdata storage in appdata onto another folder. This seemed like a memory related issue, but I couldn't research anything about it since my Chrome didn't work properly. I couldn't clear cache since nothing would load, including chrome://clear-browser-data. Not even the tabs dropdown menu loaded, and pressing "send feedback" on the crash page would give me a blank window. Trying to create a new profile also created a blank window. My C drive wasn't full, and my other programs worked fine. Chrome was rendering properly and the only thing wrong with it was it couldn't load anything.

Then I used Chrome's task manager to try to kill all the tab processes, then moved onto the service workers, but nothing worked, so I finally tried to clear the GPU process which resulted in Chrome freezing entirely.

At this point I knew I couldn't salvage anything simply by using Chrome itself, and hoped that the files and folders I copied from the userdata folder over to another folder would have my incognito tabs, cookies, everything.

So the question is: Where do I look and how do I obtain my incognito data back?

Comment: Off the record doesn't save stuff like cookies, localstorage, etc. which are vital since they contain account information I don't even remember. Also I wouldn't be able to open the page for that extension since no new pages would load, including chrome:// pages and stuff. This is a memory issue, like I mentioned.

Comment: I am using incognito mode because I am currently in a phase of life where I want to preserve everything from before last year. This includes browsing history, passwords, autofill suggestions, etc. I am aware of the capabilities and limitations of incognito mode.

Comment: Regardless, I am no longer in need of an answer for this post as of now (I hesitantly closed the window since I messed it up when ending the GPU process in desperation for a solution, so it would be in vain to obtain my incognito data back if someone answered the post at this moment.) Although it would be useful for future scenarios of the same sort. I have two other problems at the moment, https://superuser.com/questions/1757242 and https://superuser.com/questions/1756970. If you could help me with these I would be gratified.