# Urgent: Cannot run any program as administrator, gives file system error (-1073740791) on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, permissions, memory-leaks

So a program I was running just crashed because it was out of memory, and I was like, that's weird, because the only other programs I have running is task manager and chrome. So I open resource monitor and lo and behold I only have 100 MB of free memory and more than 2000 MB of standby memory. When sorting by memory usage in task manager, it says 80% of it is being used even though when adding all the processes' memory usage together it doesn't add up.

Then I do a quick google search and they tell me to download rammap. So I download it, accept the eula, and when I open it, it gives me this error:

[image]

Then I search that up online and it tells me to run disk defrag. i run it and it says that my C drive is fine. Then it tells me to diagnose and clean my c drive using cmd. So I type "cmd" into the windows search and click run as administrator, and it gives me the same error.

Then I search for an alternative, and come across "process hacker" from sourceforge. The application looks trustworthy, so I give it an install and when I open it, lo and behold, it gives me "ShellexecutionEx failed" with the same error code. Apparently it has something to do with an application shutting down because it doesn't have admin access.

Now for someone who doesn't have valuable information that cannot be saved before restart, the obvious solution would be to restart my pc, but I have 100+ tabs in chrome incognito mode that cannot be easily saved, so restarting is not an option.

Comment: "*100+ tabs in chrome incognito mode*" first time I see this reason for not being able to restart... Perhaps you can try [bookmarking all open tabs](https://www.makeuseof.com/bookmark-all-tabs-chrome-firefox-edge-brave-safari/)? A short Google journey seems to point at an issue with your system which is likely not easilyt resolved while keeping the system live and might even point to breaking hardware, so losing some open tabs might not be your worst problem.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke - 100 tabs in Chrome is nothing, I have hundreds, without a problem

Comment: Bookmarking doesn't save tab back/forward history, not to mention other valuable data like cookies, localstorage, etc. that only pertain to that certain incognito session. There is a problem with chrome developers and it's that they completely neglect the needs of power users like me, opting to spend their time to make the application more user friendly to newbies, unnecessarily changing features, often making them even worse, etc. It is comparable to the situation with microsoft. There is currently no good way to report these problems too, we must rely on third part forums like this to solve

Comment: our problems, and that itself comes with another set of nuances, such as lack of activity. Microsoft's own provided customer support website has an array of completely incompetent techies who regurgitate junk that won't help at you to improve their standing on the site, and chrome completely lacks a stable customer support website

Comment: Chrome devs have all those features in the regular mode. Incognito is a special mode where all those things are specifically NOT the point. You're expecting unreasonable things from Chrome. You need to restart in order to eliminate a very likely software culprit.

Comment: I don't think this has much to do with Chrome. Perhaps it was something I did in Chrome that caused something to switch off in my PC, and I need to know what in order to fix it.

Comment: To give some examples for my statement above, which may or may not be related to this post directly, I randomly stumbled upon this google support thread which has dozens of users berating google for their complete inaction to these problems https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2027254/gpu-process-high-ram-and-cpu-usage?hl=en. Nevertheless, I am not surprised, this is not the first nor will it be the last time I encountered a thread like that. The sad truth is that big tech just doesn't care much about power users (ie. a user base that actually cares about the product they are using)