# Photoshop CS6 will not open and keeps saying there is not enough RAM when it has worked before with less free memory

Tags: memory, adobe-photoshop, virtual-memory, memory-limit, photoshop-cs6

So this question goes hand-in-hand with another one of my posts, [Urgent: Cannot run any program as administrator, gives file system error (-1073740791) on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1756970), in that I believe they are related. I don't remember how it happened or when it started, but 'twas about a week ago when I started to not be able to open applications as administrator. Restarting file explorer seemed to have fixed it, but it came back again and this time restarting file explorer no matter how many times did not fix it. A few days ago I discovered a third party application was hogging up hundreds of megabytes of free memory, and I believed this to be the issue of why I couldn't open Photoshop, but after I had ended the process and saw my free memory gain hundreds of megabytes, I still could not open Photoshop.

So I went looking online for a solution to the Photoshop problem and there was a video that told you to add a registry key to bypass physical memory restrictions, but I cannot open registry editor as it will give me the same error as opening any other app as administrator.

Please help, this is very urgent. I am using Windows 10.

Edit: To elaborate, here are the list of issues that I mentioned in my post:

- Files cannot be run as administrator. They give a "File System Error" with the code (-1073740791)
- Photoshop CS6 cannot be run and tells me there is not enough RAM when it has run before with less available memory.

I believe these two issues are correlated in that they are possibly caused by the same event. Simply rebooting my computer can almost certainly fix these problems but I cannot do so right now due to invaluable data I am still working on that cannot be easily saved.

Comment: if the file system has been broken then the only thing you can do is to run `chkdsk /f` to try fixing it, and `sfc /scannow` to fix broken Windows files. And if the failure is due to the hard disk then you need to replace the disk and reinstall Windows

Comment: I cannot open command prompt as administrator as you can see here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Ev4.png

Comment: boot from the external Windows installation disc/pendrive. If that doesn't solve the issue then obviously you have to reinstall Windows

Comment: You need to restart your computer, if you haven't yet. Based on what you've said in your other posts, if you're still insisting on not restarting, you really need to restart

Answer (score 1):

> not be able to open applications as administrator.  ...  I discovered
> a third party application was hogging up hundreds of megabytes of free
> memory, ....   still could not open Photoshop.....  found a registry
> key to bypass physical memory restrictions, but I cannot open registry
> editor

You have many problems with this machine and it appears that constant efforts to fix have made things worse.

**Reinstall Windows.**

Back up important and needed documents, email, favorites and so on to a USB drive. Double check this.

Now check the main drive for errors and replace if necessary.

Go to Windows Settings, Update, and scroll down the right side for Recovery.  Do a Windows Reset.  This will reinstall Windows and you need to reinstall your Apps.

This is the best approach now, because the damage has been too difficult to solve.

Comment: Reinstalling Windows is the absolute last resort. This mustn't be the only way to solve my problem. I have been using this machine practically every day for years and my sentiment for it equates to the value of my entire life. It would be impossible to back up every single little detail onto a USB drive, and you just blatantly told me to only backup "the important things". This is paramount to excerebration.

Comment: In fact, I believe all these issues can simply be fixed with a reboot. But at the moment I cannot do so due to important data I am still working on that cannot be saved at all.

Comment: There are many errors so I so that is why I suggested re-installation .  I use the term "important" things to represent what is needed.

Comment: John, I am still able to browse my computer fine. Here are the list of problems:
- Cannot open any program as administrator, gives file system error (-1073740791)
- Cannot open Photoshop CS6, says that there is not enough RAM when free memory is more than 500 MB

Comment: I believe all these issues can simply be fixed with a reboot.  .....  Admin issues and memory issues like you quoted are not likely fixed with a restart.

Comment: How do you know for sure? Have you experienced the same thing? I looked at your activity John and it seems like you gravitate towards simpler subjects. My understanding of Windows could be completely different from yours. I would gladly give my life away to preserve the contents of my computer, for it is my life's work. Your blatant approach to the matter instils unnecessary fear into my heart.

Comment: When so many issues like this occur (yes I have seen this at customers), re-iinstall is generally (90%) the surest solution.

Comment: I mentioned only two issues in my original post and in one of my comments above. The second issue could very well be caused by the same thing that caused the first issue.

Comment: You had more issues in your first post - same machine.   I do things the fastest and most reliable way possible.

Comment: This philosophy can apply to real life too. Say someone is having many troubles with their life and path they can take to solve their problems is a long and hard process. Alternatively, they can end their life right then and there, and this would be the fastest and most reliable way to solve their problems. What you are saying is for me to basically end my computer's life, because to preserve everything I want preserved would take weeks if not months. There are registry keys, temporary files—imprints onto my system from years of usage that cannot be easily reproduced. I hold these things dear.

Comment: @rignecorte Sorry to be harsh, but if you are emotionally attached to temporary files and registry keys, then maybe you should re-evaluate your life priorities, because these are literally data predestined to be deleted and an implementation detail invented to let you get things done, respectively. Right now your computer is actively preventing you from getting things done. As for your analogy between reinstalling Windows and a suicide, I'm speechless.

Comment: It isn't only my emotional investment in these things. I truly believe one day I will be able to use all these bits and pieces of data to analyze the story of my life. I suppose you could call me a data hoarder. Anyway, I practically grew up on this machine. To quote from the movie Iron Man 2, "The suit and I are one, to turn it over would be to turn over myself, which is tantamount to indentured prostitution." This is how I feel about my PC. Really.

Comment: Anyway, I practically grew up on this machine   .....   With all due respects, are you old enough to be here?  I dispense with most computers after 6 to 7 years.

Comment: Without performing at least a reboot, we cannot really help, your system probably just needs a reboot

Comment: If you're a data hoarder, then learn to hoard properly. Disks always die eventually, it's only a matter of time, and backup is paramount. Think about it now or learn about it the hard way later. Given that your system is falling apart and needs reinstalling, I think you're already late.

Comment: Also: what parts of your life do you think you'll be able to dig out from temp files and registry keys? If the day you've installed Chrome is a memory worth keeping, then you may be missing out on life.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't come here to have my life be judged. My philosophy is that every bit of data, no matter how insignificant it currently may seem to be, can and will be useful for future projects. I learned this the hard way when I was careless about my data years ago and because of it I have lost my old artwork, accounts, etc.

Comment: You set yourself up by suggesting that suicide is a superior option to reinstalling Windows. Find your documents and information (NOT in the Registry or other obscure location). Back it up.  This is at worst a one day effort.  Then reinstall Windows and make your computer work. What we are asking you to do is simple and straightforward. This is not judging you.